# Map each value in pandas series/dataframe to n>1 dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I have a pandas series, and a function that takes a value in the series and returns a dataframe. Is there a way to apply the function to the series and collate the results in a natural way?

What I am really trying to do is to use pandas series/multiindex to keep track of the results in each step of my data analysis pipeline, where the multiindex holds the parameters used to get the values. For example, the series (s below) is the result of step 0 in my data analysis pipeline. In step 1, I want to try x more dimensions (2 below, thus the dataframe) and collate the results into another series.

Can we do better than below? Where `stack()` calls seem a bit excessive. Will the xarray library be a good fit for my use case?

```
In [112]: s
Out[112]:

a    0
b    1
c    2
dtype: int64

In [113]: d = s.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame([[x,x*2],[x*3,x*4]]).stack()).stack().stack()

In [114]: d
Out[114]:

a  0  0    0
      1    0
   1  0    0
      1    0
b  0  0    1
      1    3
   1  0    2
      1    4
c  0  0    2
      1    6
   1  0    4
      1    8
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a `DataSet` of 2D arrays, and align them for you. You may want to set the dimensions prior if you want them to be named a certain way / be a certain size.

`xr.Dataset(k: func(v) for k, v in series.items())`